# Wordpress get_site_url() not working sometimes

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Local by Flywheel and my local URL is: `http://sarasota-soccer-club.local/`. What I'm doing is adding a background image to a `div` in WordPress: `<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/hero-image.jpg`. The thing is that the image sometimes doesn't show. When this happens I just replace the `get_site_url()` with the local URL and the background image comes back. I'm using PHPStorm and running NGINX on macOS Ventura. Any idea what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to use the `wp_get_attachment_url()` with the images attachment ID instead?

Answer (score 2):

When using image as a background, it should be located in your theme's folder (since it's part of the style) something like this:
"/wp-content/themes/your-theme/assets/img/hero-image.jpg"

If you use this approach, then you need to call it using this function:
**get_template_directory_uri()** (that will return the path of your theme's location):

```
<div class="img" style="background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()) ?>/assets/img/hero-image.jpg)" >

</div>
```

If you want to continue using your approach you can use:

```
<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo site_url(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is with your theme because sometime theme code conflict issue is happening.

Better to use get_template_directory_uri() intead of get_site_url().

```
<div class="img" style="style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()./foldername/imagename' ?>)"
```

For Reference visit https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/